# Copy Constructors that Avoid Privacy Leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, constructor, copy-constructor

I am studying for an exam and wanted to verify that I am understanding how to build a **copy constructor that avoids privacy leaks**. Specifically a copy constructor that takes in an Object such as Bill. In this example the Bill class has instance variables Money and Date that are type object:

```
private Money amount; 
private Date dueDate;
```

and my constructor right now looks like this:

```
public Bill(Bill toCopy){
    this.amount = new Money(toCopy.amount);
    this.dueDate = new Date(toCopy.dueDate);
}
```

Do I need to make a setter/mutator method for dueDate and amount (such as setDueDate and setAmount), or can I do the above within my copy constructor? 
Also, we don't need to worry about privacy leaks with primitive types right? i.e If I had a constructor that only took in doubles

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: There's no privacy leak from a class to another object of the same class.

Comment: You're making a (hopefully) deep copy in the copy constructor. This is sufficient, unless you want want external users of your Bill to be able to set a new due date or amount after construction. Then and only then should you provide mutators. When you copy a primitive type, it's copied by value, and no link to the source remains.

Comment: @AndyThomas thank you! So inside my copy constructor I would instead call `setAmount(toCopy.amount)` and `setDueDate(toCopy.dueDate);` then build two setters `public void setAmount(Money nextAmount)` and `public void setDueDate(Date nextDueDate);` then inside each of them: `this.amount = new Money(nextAmount)` and similarly `this.dueDate = new Date(nextDueDate)`

Comment: You could do that, if you want your class to support setters. Consider whether you want a Bill to be immutable after construction. If you're just making private setters, it may be easier to just set the fields in the constructor/s.